# Resharper MSBuild Parameters

Tags: c#, msbuild, resharper

We are using Resharper's Build & Run feature.  After some recent changes we need to pass parameters to the underlying MSBuild command.  After some googling and looking at the configuration screen in Resharper options, I cannot find any place to customize this.  Is this possible?

More Detailed Notes:
The project is an Azure Cloud Service deployment project
We need to pass the `/p:TargetProfile="Local"` parameter

Resharper Build 2017.2.2
Screen shot from Resharper options
[image: Resharper Options Screenshot]

Comment: You can specify build parameters in Properties of your project. Right click on the project -> Properties -> Build Events

Comment: when you say "some parameters" - what exactly? there may be other ways to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: @dremerDT These are cloud service projects for deploying to azure. The only three options I see on the Build Events page are pre build, post build, and a drop down for Running the post build event.  I don't think I can use any of these to specify something for MSBuild.  I have updated the question to reflect that.  Thank you.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I have updated the question to include the TargetProfile parameter we need. Thanks

Comment: @leemicw, as an idea, probably you can add parameters in the .csproj file. In a PropertyGroup. <TargetProfile>Local</TargetProfile>. But it's not the best idea, because you need to add the property for each project.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a support case with JetBrains and apparently this is a known bug.  Here is a link to the bug tracker.  It is currently scheduled for version 2018.2.  They have delayed the bug before.  No work around was offered.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450390